# FB webhook doesn't get messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm trying to write bot. I cann't to get messages in my webhook. Callback seems verified (at least I don't see any error when I click on Verify button). However, checks image at left part of page isn't lighting with green. Is it normal?

Thank you

```
https://gyazo.com/f2cabb49fed652a82529e96b5401ce3c
https://gyazo.com/6b4c221a1b2743ae3204bb7050628fb1
https://gyazo.com/7a6a7246a143ad8ab955627ed1647127
https://gyazo.com/fe4fbb6369a41b4cbd4610573dd0da11
```

Comment: Are you testing with users that have a role in the app? You need to get the permissions reviewed, before it is supposed to work for anyone else.

Comment: No, I didn't use roles. Want to add when I click on Test button, it sends test messages to my webhook. https://gyazo.com/b9cd4a3046cd258b508706ddab13c9ec E.g. when I click on Test (where is feed) it sends test feeds to my webhooks. But in live mode doesn't work when I create Post and click Share :(